# Websphere MQ integration with Spring-AMQP

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-amqp

We are planning to do a POC with Websphere MQ (8.0.0.5). 
Can anyone give any pointers on how to achieve the Websphere MQ (8.0.0.5 - which supports AMQP) integration with Spring-AMQP framework.

As far as i know Spring-AMQP inherently supports RabbitMQ. 
Please let me know how this can be extended to Websphere MQ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring AMQP does not support AMQP 1.0 which (I believe) is what Websphere MQ supports.

1.0 is a very different protocol to that supported by RabbitMQ (0.9.1).

Spring currently does not have an abstraction over AMQP 1.0; there is an open [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3971) but it currently is not on the road map.

Contributions are welcome.

Comment: If not Spring-AMQP do we have any alternatives for integrating Websphere MQ (using AMQP) with Spring framework.

Comment: As I said, not at this time unless you roll your own Spring abstraction.